# Why className (with conditional operator) doesn't change when getting new value from Local Storage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

Main idea: I have a menu, and I want to store variable that indicates opening of the menu in Local Storage.

At first I wrote functions for getting and setting LocalStorage variable:

```
const getItem = (key, defaultValue) => {
    // getting item, if undefined/null return defaultValue
};

const setItem = (key, value) => {
    // just setting item, works perfect
};
```

Then I implemented custom hook, where I use these functions. The code looks like this:

```
export const useMenu = () => {
    const isOpened = Boolean(getItem("isOpened", true));
    const toggleMenu = useCallback(() => {
        setItem("isOpened", !isOpened);
    }, [isOpened]);
    
    // ...

    return {
        isOpened,
        toggleMenu,
    };
};
```

Moving to main file with component. I fetch variables with hook:

```
const { isOpened, toggleMenu } = useMenu();
```

Then in a main container I have conditional operator for className:

```
<div className={isOpened ? styles.openedContainer : styles.closedContainer}>
```

Inside the container I switch variable by click:

```
<div onClick={toggleMenu}>
```

The main problem is that my menu doesn't close! It means that className doesn't change. But at the same time onClick event works perfectly as I can see in browser's console that isOpened variable changes on time. Is there any reasons why it can happen?

*About localStorage types: yes, i know that in localStorage you can only store strings. When I get an item from localStorage I convert it to Boolean type. I checked typeof isOpened in console and it seems to be a boolean.*

```js
const { useCallback } = React;

const fakeStorage = new Map();

const styles = {
    openedContainer: "opened",
    closedContainer: "closed",
};

const getItem = (key, defaultValue) => {
    const value = fakeStorage.get(key);
    // Sadly, Stack Snippets with transpiling enabled don't understand
    // nullish coalescing, have to go old-school
    if (typeof value === "undefined") {
        return defaultValue;
    }
    return value;
};

const setItem = (key, value) => {
    fakeStorage.set(key, value);
};

/*export*/ const useMenu = () => {
    const isOpened = Boolean(getItem("isOpened", true));
    const toggleMenu = useCallback(() => {
        setItem("isOpened", !isOpened);
    }, [isOpened]);
    
    // ...

    return {
        isOpened,
        toggleMenu,
    };
};

const Example = () => {
    const { isOpened, toggleMenu } = useMenu();
    return (
        <div className={isOpened ? styles.openedContainer : styles.closedContainer}>
            <div onClick={toggleMenu}>toggle</div>
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```css
.opened {
    color: green;
}
.closed {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the change doesn't change anything React uses to know when to re-render a component. It's outside the things React knows about.

You can bring it into the things React knows about by also keeping it in a state member; here's an example with the built-in `useState`:

```
/*export*/ const useMenu = () => {
    const [isOpened, setIsOpened] = useState(Boolean(getItem("isOpened", true)));

    const toggleMenu = useCallback(() => {
        const updated = !isOpened;
        setItem("isOpened", updated);
        setIsOpened(updated);
    }, [isOpened]);
    
    // ...

    return {
        isOpened,
        toggleMenu,
    };
};
```

```js
const { useCallback, useState } = React;

const fakeStorage = new Map();

const styles = {
    openedContainer: "opened",
    closedContainer: "closed",
};

const getItem = (key, defaultValue) => {
    const value = fakeStorage.get(key);
    // Sadly, Stack Snippets with transpiling enabled don't understand
    // nullish coalescing, have to go old-school
    if (typeof value === "undefined") {
        return defaultValue;
    }
    return value;
};

const setItem = (key, value) => {
    fakeStorage.set(key, value);
};

/*export*/ const useMenu = () => {
    const [isOpened, setIsOpened] = useState(Boolean(getItem("isOpened", true)));

    const toggleMenu = useCallback(() => {
        const updated = !isOpened;
        setItem("isOpened", updated);
        setIsOpened(updated);
    }, [isOpened]);
    
    // ...

    return {
        isOpened,
        toggleMenu,
    };
};

const Example = () => {
    const { isOpened, toggleMenu } = useMenu();
    return (
        <div className={isOpened ? styles.openedContainer : styles.closedContainer}>
            <div onClick={toggleMenu}>toggle</div>
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```css
.opened {
    color: green;
}
.closed {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

There are lots of ways to spin that. There, I'm paralleling the local storage with the state variable. You could also drive the state variable via `useEffect` (and use a callback to update the state to avoid having to use `isOpened` as a dependency on `useCallback`);

```
/*export*/ const useMenu = () => {
    const [isOpened, setIsOpened] = useState(Boolean(getItem("isOpened", true)));

    useEffect(() => {
        // Update local storage
        setItem("isOpened", isOpened);
    }, [isOpened]);

    const toggleMenu = useCallback(() => {
        setIsOpened((flag) => !flag);
    }, []);
    
    // ...

    return {
        isOpened,
        toggleMenu,
    };
};
```

```js
const { useCallback, useState, useEffect } = React;

const fakeStorage = new Map();

const styles = {
    openedContainer: "opened",
    closedContainer: "closed",
};

const getItem = (key, defaultValue) => {
    const value = fakeStorage.get(key);
    // Sadly, Stack Snippets with transpiling enabled don't understand
    // nullish coalescing, have to go old-school
    if (typeof value === "undefined") {
        return defaultValue;
    }
    return value;
};

const setItem = (key, value) => {
    fakeStorage.set(key, value);
};

/*export*/ const useMenu = () => {
    const [isOpened, setIsOpened] = useState(Boolean(getItem("isOpened", true)));

    useEffect(() => {
        // Update local storage
        setItem("isOpened", isOpened);
    }, [isOpened]);

    const toggleMenu = useCallback(() => {
        setIsOpened((flag) => !flag);
    }, []);
    
    // ...

    return {
        isOpened,
        toggleMenu,
    };
};

const Example = () => {
    const { isOpened, toggleMenu } = useMenu();
    return (
        <div className={isOpened ? styles.openedContainer : styles.closedContainer}>
            <div onClick={toggleMenu}>toggle</div>
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```css
.opened {
    color: green;
}
.closed {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: The thing is that i use this menu to navigate through different pages. After switching isOpened to false and clicking on another page, className refreshes and uses isOpened=true (initial state) but in console I can see that isOpened=false. Is there any ways I can make it work?

Comment: @iwishyoujoy - The initial state shouldn't be `true` when you go to the new page with the code you've provided. The initial state isn't `true`, it's `Boolean(getItem("isOpened", true))`. `getItem` should return `false` if you've set `isOpened` to `false`.

Comment: Okay. But I don't know why when I navigate through menu (click to a different page), the value of isOpened saves but the className in main div uses opposite value, so I can still see titles of pages, in console I can see that isOpened is set like it should, but menu doesn't behave as it has to (due to wrong className). Is it something with rerender?

Comment: @iwishyoujoy - I can't help you debug something I can't see. :-) The question asked was about making the component re-render when you changed it, which this answer covers. If you have another question about other components seeming to get the wrong initial condition from local storage, that's a different question, and would need to have a [mre] showing it happening so people could help you figure it out.